# What is the best XSLT engine for Perl?

Tags: perl, apache, pdf, xhtml, xslt

I would like to know what of the many XSLT engines out there works well with Perl.

I will use Apache (2.0) and Perl, and I want to obtain PDFs and XHTMLs.

I'm new to this kind of projects so any comment or suggestion will be welcome.

Thanks.

---

Doing a simple search on Google I found a lot and I suppose that there are to many more.

- http://www.mod-xslt2.com/
- http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/
- http://saxon.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.dopscripts.com/xslt_parser.html

Any comment on your experiences will be welcome.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First mistake - [search on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=XSLT&mode=all), not Google :)

This throws up a bunch of results, but does rather highlight the problem of CPAN, that there's more than one solution, and it's not always clear which ones work, have been abandoned, are broken, slow or whatever.

And disturbingly, the best answer (or at least, one of the best) comes up on page **four** of the results :( As other folks have suggested, [XML::LibXSLT](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXSLT/) is robust and does the job:

```
  use XML::LibXSLT;
  use XML::LibXML;

  my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
  my $xslt = XML::LibXSLT->new();

  my $source = $parser->parse_file('foo.xml');
  my $style_doc = $parser->parse_file('bar.xsl');

  my $stylesheet = $xslt->parse_stylesheet($style_doc);

  my $results = $stylesheet->transform($source);

  print $stylesheet->output_string($results);
```

If you want to output results to a file then add this

```
#create output file
open(my $output_xml_file_name, '>', 'test.xml');
print $output_xml_file_name "$results";
```

If you don't want to do anything fancy, though, there's [XML::LibXSLT::Easy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXSLT-Easy/), which essentially just wraps the above in one method call (and does a bunch of clever stuff behind the scenes using [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/). Check the source for an education!).

```
  use XML::LibXSLT::Easy;

  my $p = XML::LibXSLT::Easy->new;

  my $output = $p->process( xml => "foo.xml", xsl => "foo.xsl" );
```

Answer (score 4):

So far I'm very satisfied with [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML) for non-xslt tasks, and its documentation points to [XML::LibXSLT](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXSLT), which looks quite nice, but I have no experience with it so far

Answer (score 3):

Can't really say which is the best solution because I didn't have a chance to try them all.
But I can recommend you to try Perl module [LibXSLT](http://search.cpan.org/~pajas/XML-LibXSLT-1.66/LibXSLT.pm).
It's an interface to the gnome libxslt library. I used it on one of my recent project was satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what OS but for most *nix platforms, [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXSLT) is going to be the easiest to use and install.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few Perl libraries intended to replace XSLT:

- [XPathScript](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3A%3AXPathScript)
- [XSLTish](http://search.cpan.org/~dakkar/Tree-Transform-XSLTish-0.3/lib/Tree/Transform/XSLTish.pm)
- [XSH2](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XSH2)