# How can I convert docx or wordml xml files to xsl-fo?

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo, wordml

I've been looking for a method to convert docx or wordml xml to xsl-fo.

I read this post:

[What is the best XSLT engine for Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156683/what-is-the-best-xslt-engine-for-perl)

but I'm having exceptional problems getting apache-fop going.

I was able to download the bins and run it locally but the formatting was a little off and it didn't maintain the headers and footers or section 1 or section 3 (17 page doc 3 sections).

It also overlapped the text over the outline numbers and did not maintain the font used.

Trying a more simple test caused fop to fail completely.

I would like to find a way to create a PDF that is at least close to 100% accurate reproduction of the original doc.

Comment: If you want to create PDF from docx via XSL FO using FOP, docx4j can do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the xsl.fo, but I've had good experiences with [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) for turning Microsoft documents to PDF, on Windows.  It acts as a printer driver, so I'd guess there would be a way to automatically invoke it using COM bridges from Perl, if you're hosting your webserver on Windows (or perhaps with Wine?).