# Perl convert XML to HTML using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, perl, xslt

Im a noob at perl, I was wondering if any one could help me with a task I need doing.

I have a XML file and a XSLT file, i need to use perl to some how create a html file using these two files. does any one have any ideas on where i can start, or what perl modules I can look at to help me with this ?

Comment: [XML::LibXSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156683/what-is-the-best-xslt-engine-for-perl) seems to be a good starting point

Comment: Besides Perl, maybe you can get your hands on http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As @StuartLC suggests, [XML::LibXSLT](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXSLT-1.80/LibXSLT.pm) is a good starting point. I've written a system that uses it in production on a large website. The first thing in the manual is a small example that will get you up and running.