# MediaWiki to Confluence Migration

Tags: migration, mediawiki, portability, semantic-markup, confluence

We are planning to migrate our existing MediaWiki site to Confluence. But when I searched about it, I came to know about the [Universal Wiki Converter(UWC)](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/12265453/import-from-mediawiki-to-confluence-5.7) tool, which is no longer supported or available. So, I am worried as to where to start and how to proceed. We have planned to export all the MediaWiki pages to XML and then import them to confluence.

So, my question here is whether this is a right approach and how can XML can be imported easily to Confluence?

Comment: Hey, did you tried this one:  https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DISC/HTML+To+Confluence+Converter . Found at answers: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/12265453/import-from-mediawiki-to-confluence-5.7

Comment: @ppasler thanks for the links.. Ya, i went through those links. since the uwc isnt supported anymore, i was wondering whether to proceed with the html conversion path.??

Comment: HTML conversion is a nightmare... I did not know UWC disappeared but this shows how Confluence tends to lock your data, why switch from an open data XML to something else? Anyway, you'll need to tell us how big a use of templates you make etc., to be able to answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use Markdown as the universal format for import/export. Markdown can be imported or exported to MediaWiki:

> Markdown-Wiki
>
> Simple tool for converting wiki 2 markdown and other way round.
>
> Install
>
> Tool expects that you have npm installed on your system.

```
npm install markdown-wiki
```

> Usage

```
cat foo.wiki | markdown2wiki > foo.md
```

and Confluence can render Markdown:

> Markdown for Confluence provides macros that render Markdown content on Confluence pages. The content can be entered directly in the body of a the markdown macro or be from an attachment or URL.

or Markdown can be converted to HTML and rendered by Confluence:

```
npm install markdown-html

markdown-html in.md -o out.html
```

XML export would require XSLT or [some equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156683/what-is-the-best-xslt-engine-for-perl/44009299#44009299) to convert from the [MediaWiki XML Schema](https://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.8.xsd) to the [Confluence XML Schema](http://www.amnet.net.au/%7Eghannington/confluence/readme.html), if the above is not a viable option.

**References**

- [Markdown for Confluence](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/MARKDOWN/Markdown+for+Confluence)
- [Confluence Command Line Interface](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CSOAP/Confluence+Command+Line+Interface)
- [UPM CLI Reference](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/UPMCLI/Reference)
- [markdown-wiki: A Bidirectional WikiText to Markdown converter](https://github.com/Gozala/markdown-wiki)
- [markdown-html: Command line tool for markdown to html conversion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-html)
- [Confluence Storage Format - Atlassian Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-storage-format-790796544.html)
- [Confluence to Markdown Converter](https://github.com/highsource/confluence-to-markdown-converter)
- [Markdown Implementations - Markdown Community Group](https://www.w3.org/community/markdown/wiki/MarkdownImplementations)
- [Extension Matrix/AllExtensions - MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_Matrix/AllExtensions)
- [Microsoft Word Macros - MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word_Macros)
- [MarkDoc](http://markdoc.org/)

Comment: Where do I find the .wiki files? When I use the special export, it generates .xml files. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Also it is not officially supported the UWC still works. I managed to migrate a moinmoin-wiki to confluence about a year ago. Still needed lots of manual tweaking and scripting as UWC is more a tool than a ready-to-use solution.

Start here:
https://migrations.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/UWC/overview

Source with build intructions: 
https://bitbucket.org/appfusions/universal-wiki-converter